# Postgresql behaviour between diferent stages

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-tuning, performance-tuning

I have three Postgresql instances (Postgresql clusters) in three diferent stages.
The instances are the sames with the same datas and the same parameters.
But i do not have the same behaviour between one stage and the two others.

For example, a query is executed in 5 minutes in one stage and in 3 seconds in the two others.
I checked the execution plan and one index was not used causing a slow full scan. After some manipulations like vacuum analyze, running the query with enable_seq_scan to false (and reset to true after some runnings) and after the week-end, the index was used and this query was executed in 12 seconds. It is still slower.

In general, the behaviour is slower than the two others.
The systems are the sames (rhel 7, ram, cpu) and postgresql.conf (shared_buffers, etc) are the sames too.
The servers are dedicated for the databases.

Have you got some ideas about the issue ?
What are the parameters i have to check and compare. I surely missed something.

Rhel 7
Postgresql 9.5.12

EDIT
Hereunder some parameters with diferent values between the two stages:

some parameters from the stage which does not work well:

```
work_mem = 60MB
maintenance_work_mem = 14GB
checkpoint_timeout = 30min
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
max_wal_size = 13GB
wal_keep_segments = 1000
```

Some parameter from the stage working well:

```
work_mem = 50MB
maintenance_work_mem = 15GB
checkpoint_timeout = 1h
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
max_wal_size = 512GB
wal_keep_segments = 150
```

Comment: As you have discovered, how the data is organized on disk and how accurate the statistics are may affect performance. Can you take a backup of one that works well and restore it onto one that doesn't and see if they still differ?

Comment: Good idea ! Do you mean perform a dump or a cluster backup ?

Comment: Not sure what I mean:-) Whatever is easiest that will make the systems as equal as possible. If there still is a difference there might be an issue with hardware.

Comment: Check everything related to autovacuum.

Comment: @Lennart I prepared a dump but i could not yet load it because some tests are on going. I will reload the stage if the hardware investigation is not concluding.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek autovacuum parameters are the sames. I edit more informations regarding postgresql.conf. I am surprised by a 512Gb max_wal_size. It may be a mistake. I will check this with the other dba.